# What kind of vector is $\mathbb{R}^{3m}$?

Tags: vectors

What kind of vector is $\mathbb{R}^{3m}$?

As used in e.g. this paper:

Liu, Tiantian, et al. "Fast simulation of mass-spring systems." ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG) 32.6 (2013): 1-7.], p. 3.
[https://www.cs.utah.edu/~ladislav/liu13fast/liu13fast.pdf](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Eladislav/liu13fast/liu13fast.pdf)

Intuitively it's $m$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ points, but I wonder if they're just listed in a single vector, rather than using some kind of subvector construct.

Comment: A vector in $\Bbb R^n$ with $n=3m$?

Comment: @MartinR Yes likely, but I was confused as to how the calculations work out, because this suggests that one must know that the elements inside are in groups of three.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{3m}$ is not a vector. It is the space of all vectors with $2m$ real coordinates.

Comment: @mavavilj Typo, I meant $3m$.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately all real vector spaces of fixed dimension are the same so it doesn't really matter. Formerly vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3m}$ are just tuples $$(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{3m}),$$ however in the paper you link the authors are using $\mathbb{R}^{3m}$ to parameterise systems of $m$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$: $$p_1=(v_{11},v_{12},v_{13}),$$$$p_2=(v_{21},v_{22},v_{23}),$$$$\vdots$$$$p_m=(v_{m1},v_{m2},v_{m3}).$$

Thus conceptually it might be easier to think about $\mathbb{R}^{3m}$ as the space of $m\times 3$ matrices, and the system of $m$ points as given by $$\begin{pmatrix}v_{11}&v_{12}&v_{13}\\v_{21}&v_{22}&v_{23}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\v_{m1}&v_{m2}&v_{m3}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I think that one should add the notion that the jump to $^{(n)m}$, where $n$ is the length of an element, leads to the element-wise multiplication being a dot product of length $n$ vectors. So in fact one can also write that vector/matrix using $p_i$s.

Comment: So in fact the convention is the same as here: https://github.com/dilevin/CSC417-a2-mass-spring-3d#a-spring-and-two-masses-in-3d